# Python plot_surface set Y limits to center at 0

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, physics

I'm using cylindric coordinates, created a `meshgrid` and tried to plot using `plot_surface`. My full dataset doesn't get properly drawn because the scaling on the Y-axis is not correct.

I'm trying to plot the magnetic field values versus `Z` and `P`(rho) values. `Z` can be both negative and positive. `P`(rho) can only be positive.

The problem is that `p` (Y-axis) always starts from `0` to `10` (giving `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`) whereas I'd like to have it like: `10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10` so that its centered at `0`.

So this is my example code. I won't add the calculations for the magnetic field. These are not relevant for this issue.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

# Define the plane over which fields are computed.
# N must be odd to include the point (0,0).
M = 26  # No. of points along the rho axis.
N = 51  # No. of points along the z axis.
p1 = np.linspace(0, a, M)
p = np.concatenate([p1[::-1][:-1], p1])  # Make it symmetric.
z = np.linspace(-d, d, N)
p, z = np.meshgrid(p, z)  # Create grid of (p,z).

# CALCULATE magnetic field bt. So assume this is done here...
bt = np.sqrt(np.power(bz, 2) + np.power(bp, 2))

ax.plot_surface(z, p, bt, cmap=plt.cm.YlGnBu_r)
plt.show()
```

So when making adding the line,

```
p = np.concatenate([p1[::-1][:-1], p1])
```

the dimensions are broken and `plot_surface` is rightfully complaining. I'd expect this line would center the 0 in the middle of the array.

Thanks.

Comment: So what exact problem you face "making the array symmetric"? To give a solution to a problem (even if that is simple) one needs to know the problem first. Best create a [mcve] which is runnable and can be tested.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Updated the code with a minimal, complete and verifiable example. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Are you trying to manipulate the ticklabels or the data?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Ticklabels, the matrix with data that I've created is ok. It contains a symmetric array of e.g. data `p = [3 2 1 0 1 2 3]`. But when such an array is passed to `ax.plotsurface` it starts the ticklabels from `0`. I'd expect to see it starting from `3`.

Comment: I see. I think there is a misconception about ticks and axes in play. Cartesian axes always are increasing and they are completely indpendent on the data being shown, apart from the limits which are often adjusted to the minimum and maximum of the data.